# How to I edit a style inside an iframe using React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

I need to render an iframe inside a react component but want to hide an element inside it. The iframe's domain is external though.

Is there any way I can inject in custom CSS in the `iframe` and do what I need?

Here is my component:

```js
import React from 'react'

const ExampleComponent = () => {
  return ( <>
    <iframe src="https://app.sli.do/event/6ouwoyzr"></iframe>
  </> );
}
 
export default ExampleComponent;
```

And the css I want to inject:

```css
app-header {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

U should `jsx`. U can give `**className**` **attribiute** inside `iframe` tag and u can write some `jsx` code inside of it or u can create class and give it in **className**. For example :

style.css:

```
.Burger{
width:100px;
height:100px
}
```

reactfile:

```
import classesfrom 'your.css.file.path.css';

<iframe className={classes.Burger}>
```

Also u can checkout this link for other way to push into our component styling:
https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Comment: I don't want to style the iframe, I want to style the content of the page inside the iframe.

Comment: Maybe u can create other custom component inside iframe and u can give custom css of it. Or u can wrap iframe and configure it.